# ¿Cómo paso el value de un select a una función ? REACT

Tags: reactjs

Buen día tengo un select en el cual obtengo un valor

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onInputChangeResort.bind(this)} name='clienteint' className='form-control form-control-sm col-sm-8'>
                                                <option value="0">Select ...</option>
                                                { this.state.hotels.map((hotels)=>
                                                    <option key={hotels.value} value={hotels.value}>{hotels.text}</option>)
                                                }
                                            </select>
```

El valor se guarda en el estado "value"

quiero pasar ese valor en una función de la siguiente manera

```
roomtype(){
        fetch("/api-rest/agency/rooms/"+this.state.value, {
            method : 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'text/plain',
                'Authorization': "Bearer admin"
            }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                let data = responseJson.data.map(rooms => {return {value:rooms.room_type_category, text:rooms.room_category_desc}});
                this.setState({
                    room : data,
                })
            })

            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

En esta funcion hago el cambio de value para el selecrt

```
onInputChangeResort(e){
        this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    }


{/*
La funcion roomtype llena un select mapeando el state "room"
*/}

<select name='RoomType' id='IDRoomType' className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-8">
     <option value="0">Select ...</option>
     { this.state.room.map((room)=>
        <option key={room.value} value={room.value}>{room.text}</option>)
      }
 </select>
```

Mi problema es que al pasar el estado me toma el valor inicial y no el valor que se obtiene del select.

Comment: ¿Ejecutas `roomtype` inmediatamente después del `setState`?

Comment: Sería bueno saber en qué momento ejecutas tu función de `roomtype`

Comment: ya edite la pregunta agregue el select que se debe llenar con la información de la funcion roomtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el código propuesto, no llamas a `roomtype` en ningún momento, por lo cual nunca se va a setear `room` en el state.

deberías llamar a `roomtype` al momento de actualizar `value` en `onInputChangeResort`:

```
onInputChangeResort() {
  this.setState({
    value:e.target.value
  }, this.roomtype);
}
```

Hacemos uso del segundo parámetro de setState, que es un callback que se llama cuando el state ya haya sido actualizado.